# Meaning of the inverted copula

Tags: cross-linguistic, comparative-linguistics, meaning

I just discovered the existence of the inverted copula concept.

Learning a bit of Latin, you have the structure:

Subject - Copula - Predicate.

But as the case is the same in Latin for the Subject and Predicate because of the presence of the copula.

The subject of my question is not about the Latin word order and how to recognize a predicate and a subject, it's about the fact that mirror structure do exist in many languages. Copula vs inverted copula.

I'm curious about the comparison of the meaning between a copula and its inverted copula.

There are few info about this, for instance, I've found no occurrence of this linguistic phenomenon on this site.

I wanted to know if there were languages, with free word order, where it's not possible to make the difference between a copula and an inverted copula.

And what are the conditions in a same language to make the copula have a different meaning of the inverted copula, and the condition for the copula to have exactly the same meaning.

What are the languages where this phenomenon (same meaning) occurs, and the one where the different meaning occurs.